# Default value for a key defined with pgfkeys

Tags: pgfkeys

Hereafter is a simple macro with keys `nom` and `prenom` defined with `pgfkeys.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\pgfkeys{
    /test/pgf/.cd,
    nom/.store in = \nom,
    nom/.default = toto,
    prenom/.store in = \prenom,
    prenom/.default = titi,
}

\newcommand{\qui}[1][]{
    \pgfkeys{/test/pgf/.cd,#1}
    I am \prenom{} \nom{} !
}

\begin{document}
\qui[prenom = toto, nom = titi]
\end{document}
```

The issue is that if you use macro `\qui` without the key `\nom` or `\prenom` you get an error message saying `! Undefined control sequence.` I think that when I execute the macro with `\qui[nom = titi]` LaTeX does not know the macro `\prenom` and thus gives me an error message.

I do not understand why I got this error since I give a default value to all keys with the `.default` handler. I tried also the `.initial` handler but if you want the macro to work you have to replace `\prenom` and `\nom` by `\pgfkeysvalueof{prenom}` and `\pgfkeysvalueof{nom}`.

[PGF Keys differences between .initial and .default](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50856/pgf-keys-differences-between-initial-and-default)

But the following code works. You can use macro `\qui` without any keys. But again I do not understand why the `.default` handler does not do this job ?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\pgfkeys{
    /test/pgf/.cd,
    nom/.store in = \nom,
    nom = toto,
    prenom/.store in = \prenom,
    prenom = titi,
}

\newcommand{\qui}[1][]{
    \pgfkeys{/test/pgf/.cd,#1}
    I am \prenom{} \nom{} !
}

\begin{document}
\qui[prenom = toto, nom = titi]
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `.default` value is only used if you call the `prenom` key without a value. If you don't call the `prenom` key at all, it isn't executed, and therefore the `\prenom` macro isn't defined. The usual thing to do in a case like this would be to say `prenom/.store in = \prenom, prenom/.default = titi, prenom`, i.e. define the key, set its default, and call it once (using the default value) to make sure the macro is defined.

Comment: Quick, short and efficient ! Nice comment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem with your first example is that, despite the fact that key `nom` actually has a value, that value is never stored in macro `\nom`, so that macro remains undefined. `pgfkeys` only will create `\nom` and store in it the value of the key `nom` when the key `nom` is executed. Only then the value of `nom` is retrieved (and if none was assigned the default one is used) and stored in `\nom`.

So your problem is that you have to "execute" `nom` and `prenom` keys. You can do it a three different places:

- When calling command `\qui`, as for example: `\qui[nom, prenom]`. Since you are executing those keys but not assigning them a value, defaults are used.
- Inside `\qui` macro definition:

  ```
  \newcommand{\qui}[1][]{
      \pgfkeys{/test/pgf/.cd, nom, prenom, #1}
      I am \prenom{} \nom{} !
  }
  ```

  This way you can use simply `\qui{}` in main program. If you use instead `\qui[nom=foo]`, this value will override the default one.
- Inside the initial `\pgfkeys` definition:

  ```
  \pgfkeys{
      /test/pgf/.cd,
      nom/.default = toto,
      nom/.store in = \nom,
      prenom/.store in = \prenom,
      prenom/.default = titi,
      nom, prenom
  }
  ```

  This has the same effect than the second option, and it is more general, so it should be the preferred one.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This kind of short and simple example strongly lack in the pgfmanual. But maybe pgfkeys was not created to do so simple things.