# How to execute default option when using pgfopts?

Tags: pgfkeys, package-options, pgfopts

I would like to define options for a package using pgfopts. So far it works quite well, but I can't figure out how to execute default options. This is described here: [How do you define a default choice in pgfkeys](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/263012/158962) but for some reason it does not work in my test package.

Let the package be

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{testpack}[2019/10/01 v0.1]

\RequirePackage{pgfopts}
\pgfkeys{
  /testpack/.cd,
  lastword/.is choice,
  lastword/yes/.code=\AtEndDocument{\par Yes last word.},
  lastword/no/.code=\AtEndDocument{\par No last word.},
  lastword/.default=no
}
\ProcessPgfPackageOptions*
```

and the test document

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage[lastword=yes]{testpack}
%\usepackage[lastword=no]{testpack}
\usepackage{testpack}

\begin{document}
Here is the text.
\end{document}
```

then the first two load options give the desired behavior. However, when loading `testpack` without any options no code is executed at all. I assumed that the `.default` statement does this trick, but apparently it does not.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for `.initial`. `.default` sets a default value which is applied if the key is specified but no value is supplied. *But* `.initial` doesn't work for subkeys (from the manual "Note that no subkeys are involved."). So the easiest way to set an initial value for your choice key is to use `lastword=no`. But bear in mind that since this is code it inserts an `\AtEndDocument` each time it is called, so you'd get `\par No last word.\par Yes last word.` if you'd then use the option `lastword=yes` later on.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents*}{testpack.sty}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{testpack}[2019/10/01 v0.1]

\RequirePackage{pgfopts}
\pgfkeys{
  /testpack/.cd,
  lastword/.is choice,
  lastword/yes/.code=\AtEndDocument{\par Yes last word.},
  lastword/no/.code=\AtEndDocument{\par No last word.},
  lastword=no
}
\ProcessPgfPackageOptions*
\end{filecontents*}

%\usepackage[lastword=yes]{testpack}
%\usepackage[lastword=no]{testpack}
\usepackage{testpack}

\begin{document}
Here is the text.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. Dumb question: subkey meaning that it is in /testpack/lastword?? Would /lastword work with .initial?

Comment: @carlosvalderrama if it wasn't a choice key but a key storing information directly it would. `.initial` doesn't apply to keys which are in `testpack/lastword/...`, but only to `testpack/lastword` (as far as I understand from the documentation, I'm not entirely sure whether I got that right).

Answer (score 0):

For what it is worth, I resolved the problem by checking whether any method has been called. If not, the package still needs initialization and there I can call the desired code.

The updated package looks like

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{testpack}[2019/10/01 v0.1]
%
\newif\if@testpack@needs@init@
\@testpack@needs@init@true
%
\newcommand{\testpack@handle@yes}{%
  \@testpack@needs@init@false
  \AtEndDocument{\par Yes last word.}
}
\newcommand{\testpack@handle@no}{%
  \@testpack@needs@init@false
  \AtEndDocument{\par No last word.}
}
%
\RequirePackage{pgfopts}
\pgfkeys{
  /testpack/.cd,
  lastword/.is choice,
  lastword/yes/.code=\testpack@handle@yes{},
  lastword/no/.code=\testpack@handle@no{},
}
\ProcessPgfPackageOptions*
%
\if@testpack@needs@init@
\testpack@handle@no{}
\fi
```

The code gives the expected results now. What do you think? Any thoughts on the robustness of this approach?

Comment: Try with `\usepackage[lastword=no,lastword=yes]{testpack}`...

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution.

The `testpack.sty` file:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{testpack}[2019/10/01 v0.1]
% 
% 
\RequirePackage{pgfopts}
\pgfkeys{
  /testpack/.cd,
  lastword/.is choice,
  lastword/yes/.code={
    \def\testpack@at@end@document{\AtEndDocument{\par Yes last word.}}
  },
  lastword/no/.code={
    \def\testpack@at@end@document{\AtEndDocument{\par No last word.}}
  },
  lastword=no,
}
\ProcessPgfPackageOptions*
\testpack@at@end@document
```

Then, a test file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[lastword=yes,lastword=no]{testpack}

\begin{document}
AAA
\end{document}
```