# Keys get default values when they are not listed in the macro \pgfkeys

Tags: pgfkeys

Keys can be set a default value by the handler `/.default` in `pgfkeys`. However, when this is used, the name of the key has to be in the list of `\pgfkeys`(e.g. \pgfkeys{mykey}).
My question is: how to make a key get a default value when this key is not in the list of \pgfkeys.
Here is my code example for illustration.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\begin{document}

\pgfkeys{mykey/.code=#1} 
\pgfkeys{} % I want to get a typeset of "3" for example

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is only an example. There maybe many options in terms of "key=value" in a macro, but user need not specify every option when calling this macro. For those option arguments that do not appear in the list of \pgfkeys, I want to give them default values.

Comment: That is to say, not all options argument have to appear in the macro calling which has more than one optional arguments in terms of "key=value".

Comment: Thank you marmot for your good info. I think my example is poor which do not explain my real purpose. Yet I just find a solution to my question at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85754/default-value-for-a-key-defined-with-pgfkeys .

Comment: To be honest I do not really understand the point of your question. Could you please clarify what you mean with "is not in the list of pgfkeys"? Undefined keys which should have a default?

Comment: @TeXnician There is a macro, for example, \mycmd, it should be call like this: \mycmd[key1=val1,key2=val2,key3=val3,...]{...}. However in many cased, it's unnessessory to specify all these keys. May be \mycmd[key2=val2]{...} is enough in which key1, key3,...keyn have their default values.

Comment: And where's the problem if you have defined the keys with an initial value? (Note: `initial` not `default`)

Comment: @TeXnician \pgfkeys{
  aa/.code=#1,
  aa/.default=aa,
  aa/.initial=aa,
  bb/.code=#1,
  }
\pgfkeys{bb=bb} you see, aa will not be typeset even if "/.initial" is used

Comment: And that's obviously correct, because `\pgfkeys` does set the keys, but not invoke them/gets the value. You should read the manual.