# Declaring patterns with variables in TikZ: understanding the effect of the variables

Tags: tikz-pgf, pattern

I'm trying to understand `\pgfdeclarepatternformonly` from page 1064 of the TikZ manual. I'm experimenting with the `rings` pattern given there as an example. If I compile the example as given, I get the expected result. However, I don't fully understand what the variables are doing. In particular, I don't understand the effect of `radius`.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}
  % page 1064 of manual
  \pgfdeclarepatternformonly[/tikz/radius,\thickness,\size]{rings}
  {\pgfpoint{-0.5*\size}{-0.5*\size}}
  {\pgfpoint{0.5*\size}{0.5*\size}}
  {\pgfpoint{\size}{\size}}
  {
    \pgfsetlinewidth{\thickness}
    \pgfpathcircle\pgfpointorigin{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/radius}}
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
  }
  \newdimen\thickness
  \tikzset{
    radius/.initial=4pt,
    size/.store in=\size, size=20pt,
    thickness/.code={\thickness=#1},
    thickness=0.75pt
  }

  \begin{tikzpicture}[rings/.style={pattern=rings}]
    \filldraw [draw=blue, rings] (0,0) rectangle +(5,5);
    \filldraw [draw=green, rings, radius=7pt] (0,0) rectangle +(5,5);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Possibly rather simple-mindedly, I expected that changing the `radius` would alter the size of the circles drawn. However, that appears not the be the case. That is, if I comment the second pattern line, I get precisely the same looking pattern but in blue, rather than a pattern with smaller circles as I would have expected. (If I set `opacity=.5` for the second line, I get blue-green circles as the green is superimposed precisely over the blue.)

So what is `radius` doing exactly?

[image: rings pattern]

Comment: @HarishKumar Thanks! Is the example in the manual wrong? Or am I missing something else?

Comment: According to manual your example should work. I don't know why we need to change `radius/.initial` instead of `radius`.

Comment: @HarishKumar Thanks again. Do you want to post an answer? I'd like to wait to see if anybody offers an explanation but I'd be happy to give you an upvote in the meantime.

Comment: (off topic) In my case, all circles are black...

Comment: @Symbol1 How odd.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Keys works fine. The problem is that `radius` is used to set the radii of ellipses. Therefore `radius=` is rather an *action* then a simple assignment. We cannot see the effect of `radius=7pt` here because it is about `x radius` and `y radius`.

There are two ways to fix this. The first one is to use another variable name, for instance `/tikz/rings/radius`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}
  % page 1064 of manual
  \pgfdeclarepatternformonly[/tikz/rings/radius,\thickness,\size]{rings}
  {\pgfpoint{-0.5*\size}{-0.5*\size}}
  {\pgfpoint{0.5*\size}{0.5*\size}}
  {\pgfpoint{\size}{\size}}
  {
    \pgfsetlinewidth{\thickness}
    \pgfpathcircle\pgfpointorigin{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/rings/radius}}
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
  }
  \newdimen\thickness
  \tikzset{
    rings/radius/.initial=4pt,
    size/.store in=\size, size=20pt,
    thickness/.code={\thickness=#1},
    thickness=0.75pt
  }

  \begin{tikzpicture}[rings/.style={pattern=rings}]
    \filldraw [draw=blue, rings] (0,0) rectangle +(5,5);
    \filldraw [draw=green, rings, rings/radius=7pt] (0,0) rectangle +(5,5);
  \end{tikzpicture}
```

Otherwise it is not hard to rewrite the drawing procedure.

[image]

```
  \pgfdeclarepatternformonly[/tikz/x radius,/tikz/y radius,\thickness,\size]{Rings}
  {\pgfpoint{-0.5*\size}{-0.5*\size}}
  {\pgfpoint{0.5*\size}{0.5*\size}}
  {\pgfpoint{\size}{\size}}
  {
    \pgfsetlinewidth{\thickness}
    \pgfpathellipse\pgfpointorigin
                  {\pgfpoint{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/x radius}}{0pt}}
                  {\pgfpoint{0pt}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/y radius}}}
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
  }
  \newdimen\thickness
  \tikzset{
    radius=4pt,
    size/.store in=\size, size=20pt,
    thickness/.code={\thickness=#1},
    thickness=0.75pt
  }

  \begin{tikzpicture}[Rings/.style={pattern=Rings}]
    \filldraw [draw=blue,Rings] (0,0) rectangle +(5,5);
    \filldraw [draw=green,Rings,x radius=7pt,y radius=1pt] (0,0) rectangle +(5,5);
  \end{tikzpicture}
```

### About `.initial`

According to [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50856/pgf-keys-differences-between-initial-and-default), `.initial`, comparing to `.default`, is used while the key is supposed to store a value. Since Ti*k*Z is not doing type-checking carefully, a `radius/.initial=7pt` will store the value aside the original function of `radius=`. At the end we can see that value through `\pgfkeysvalueof`. But we cannot modify it by `radius=` becuses the latter is doing its old job.

### About the original example

If you look at it very carefully, you will found that radii never change. It seems to work because clipping boxes result in small pieces while thick circles seem large. Nevertheless, one may blame on [moon illusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moon_illusion).
(And that makes it a fantastic psychological practice.)

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But why does the example in the manual seem to work? That just uses `radius=...` and that's what I don't understand.

Comment: @cfr It never works. But still took me 20min to figure it out.

Comment: Thank you so much. I sat and thought about this for a bit to figure out what was going on in the example and I think I almost understand it now ;). So the manual is definitely wrong, and I was not just missing something blindingly obvious! (At least, not something I'd expect to be obvious to me relative to my understanding of TikZ ;).) I'd (+1) this again if I could, but I can at least give you a tick.