# Difference between an option's default and its initial value

Tags: tikz-pgf

In the description of the `/tikz/shape` node option on p. 216 of the TikZ & PGF manual for version 3.0.1a states:

> no default, initially `rectangle`

It goes on to explain that this option selects

> the shape either of the current node or, when this option is not given inside a node but somewhere outside, the shape of all nodes in the current scope.

What is the difference between an option that has a default value and one that has initially a certain value? If instead of initially being `rectangle` the `/tikz/shape` would be `rectangle` by default, what would change in its behavior and the way it can be used?

Can someone please explain and demonstrate the differences with a minimal example?

---

The present question is similar to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/50856/21685). However that question deals with PGF (which I am unfamiliar with), whereas the current question deals with TikZ.

PGF and TikZ are two separate levels. Consider the following quote from the manual (p. 221):

> Both PGF and TikZ support such multipart nodes. On the lower level, PGF provides a system for specifying that a shape consists of several parts. On the TikZ level, you specify the different node parts by using the following command:
>
> `\nodepart[<options>]{<part name>}`

The point of this quote is to show that the same feature can have different manifestations in PGF vs. in TikZ and it is reasonable to ask how a certain feature manifests in one level and how it manifests in another level, and this would constitute two different questions, just as a question about TikZ's `\nodepart` command can coexist with a question about PGF's system for specifying that a shape consists of several parts without any of these questions being a duplicate of the other.

My question is: Is it possible to explain the difference and to give a minimal example using only TikZ concepts and syntax without resorting to low level PGF? Is the difference perceptible from a high-level user's perspective who only knows TikZ? (I am such a user.)

Comment: Both `tikz` and `pgf` use the same key management system, so I think that the question you marked (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50856/pgf-keys-differences-between-initial-and-default) is really a duplicate.

Comment: This is a duplicate of the previous one as tikz is layered over pgf (they have the same manual) and uses pgfkeys.

Comment: @Rmano: The question is: Is it possible to explain the difference and to give a minimal example using only TikZ concepts and syntax without resorting to low level PGF tinkering? Is the difference perceptible in code that uses only TikZ? It's like asking whether a certain Java bytecode concept or construct can be expressed or distinguished using the Java language.

Comment: As the `shape` key has not default value, you can't write `\node[shape]{...}`. You must provide a value (like  `\node[shape=circle]{...}`). As `shape` has an initial value (`rectangle`), with `\node{...}` you get a rectangular node.

Comment: @Evan, tried it.

Comment: It just says the key is initialized with the value `rectangle` but does not have a default value.

Comment: `shape` doesn't use `/.initial` or `/.default` handlers.

Comment: I suspect that there are two different things here --- one of them are the `/.initial` and `/.default` keys, and another one what the manual means when they say "default *whatever*, initial value *whatever else*"  --- that can be implemented with that keys or not.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This answer is for explaining what the TikZ/PGF manual means for default/initial values of a keyword. It may or may not have any relation with [the usage of `.default` and `.initial` keys](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50856/pgf-keys-differences-between-initial-and-default) depending on the specific implementation.

For example for `shape:`

- `no default` means you can't say

  ```
   \node[shape, red]{...}
  ```

  because there is no default (in this case the key is defined so that it must have an argument, so it will error out if you do; thanks, @percusse). If, for example, it *had* `circle` as default, that means that you could have used the aforementioned command to have a circle-shaped node;
- `initial` means that if you say

  ```
  \node[color=red] {...}
  ```

  *without* mentioning  `shape` you'll have a `rectangle`.

Another example could be (straight from the manual):

> `/pgf/tips=value`          (default `true`, initially `on draw`) 
>   alias `/tikz/tips`
>
> This key governs in what situations arrow tips are added to a path.
>   The following values are permissible:
>
> - `true` (the value used when no value is specified)
> - `proper`
> - `on draw` (the initial value, if the key has not yet been used at all)
> - `on proper draw`
> - `never` or `false` (same effect)
>
> [...]

(although I don't understand what the comment on the last item means --- just that `never` and `false` are the same?)

Comment: Thanks. Just to make sure I understand: if a certain option `x` doesn't have an initial value, it means that given an object `a` that this option applies to, there isn't necessarily an answer to the question: "What is the value of `a`'s option `x`?", because `a` may not have this option at all. And on the contrary, if an option has an initial value, then it is meaningful to ask the above question for every object `a` that this option applies to, because `a` will always have this option, the only unknown is the value this option has. Correct?

Comment: Another question: can an option have both an initial and a default values? If so, which one "wins"? For instance, suppose a `node` had an option `my_opt` with initial value `a` and default `b`. What would be the value of the option in the following cases: (1) `node []` (the option is not specified)? (2) `node [my_opt]` (the option is specified without an explicit value)?

Answer (score 6):

This is the case where it sounds like the problem is related to keys but `shape` is a pretty legacy keyword and the way it is defined is pretty straightforward.

```
\tikzoption{shape}{\edef\tikz@shape{#1}}
```

(`\tikzoption` later became `\tikzset`. So don't use it)

Then at the initialization of TikZ package we see

```
\def\tikz@shape{rectangle}%
```

Note that this is the global scope so if you don't fiddle with it every TikZ picture will inherit this default value. This is **not** related to `/.initial` and `/.default` problem. It's the manual's classification that makes it looks like key issue.

---

In the manual if you see `no default` this means you need to supply a value. If you see `no value` then,... well... you don't need to provide a value. If you insist on providing a value sometimes you get an error, sometimes not.

Example,

```
\node[matrix of math nodes={4}{5}] {\tan \\ \sin};
```

will not error. Because every style/code handler intrinsically accepts arguments. If not explicitly set by `/.value forbidden`  handler then nothing happens.

`Initially <...>` means *if you don't provide anything else I'm going to use* `<...>`.

As usual, exceptions apply...

One final note about TikZ/PGF difference. All TikZ is converted to PGF code so there are no separate functionalities. It's a matter of syntax.